# CakePHP: Nested URLs

Tags: cakephp

I want to use the pages' slug path for the URL (ie: /products/stereos/stereo-1/info - this just directly follows the pages' tree structure in the db: info is a child of stereo-1, stereo-1 is a child of stereos, etc). (Everything will be managed through the Pages controller).

One way I was thinking was to do something like this:

```
// routes: (code found on another thread):
Router::connect('/:site/:language/:row:lastslash',array(
    'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'parseURL',),
    array(
        'pass'=>array('row'),
        'row'=>'.*?',
        'lastslash'=>'\/?'
    )
);
```

This should forward me to parseURL with the rest of the URL in $row. Once in parseURL, I can find the actual post id (by using the slug path), get the db field that specifies the action, and then forward there. In theory, the system should handle any url tree path that is in the database. For example:

/page1/page2/page3/info/thisPage - parseURL would run through each portion of the url to find the post ID for 'thisPage'. 'thisPage' would have an 'action' field specifying which action to use, and parseURL would redirect there.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky problem.

The way I've done it is by making an SEO routes file in /app/tmp/cache/seo_routes.php, which is loaded on every request.

This routes file is autogenerated and updated by an SEO behavior that you attach to each model.

It contains lines like this:

```
Router::connect('/content/about-us', array(
            'plugin' => 'content',
            'controller' => 'content',
            'action' => 'view',
            16));
```

This means that when you make a new model, you can just add these lines to the model:

```
    /**
 * @var actsAs A list of Behaviours to use 
 */
public $actsAs = array(
    'Seo'
);
```

and whenever you save a record, the seo routes file is updated.

By default, the SEO behavior will make its own slug, but you can override this in your model by adding a getSlug($data) function.  You need these functions in your appModel:

```
    /**
 * Returns the display name for this model with the data provided
 * @param $data
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDisplayName($data){

    $displayName = $data[$this->displayField];

    return $displayName;
}

/**
 * Gets the SEO slug (short title) for the item
 * @param $data
 * @return string
 */
public function getSlug($data){

    $displayName = $this->getDisplayName($data);
    $slug = $this->createSlugFromString($displayName);

    return $slug;
}

/**
 * Creates a slug from an input string
 * @param $string
 * @return string
 */
public function createSlugFromString($string) {
    $slugParts = explode('.', $string);

    foreach($slugParts as $slugIndex => $slugPart){
        $slugParts[$slugIndex] = strtolower(Inflector::slug($slugPart, '-'));
    }
    $slug = implode('.', $slugParts);

    return $slug;
}
```

In your case, you would override the getSlug function to return the nested path that you require.

Inside your seoBehavior you need something like this:

```
/**
 * afterSave Callback
 * Creates a new SEO record if required
 *
 * @param Model $model Model the callback is called on
 * @param boolean $created Whether or not the save created a record.
 * @return void
 */
public function afterSave(Model $model, $created) {

    $modelPrimaryKey = $model->id;

    // See if we already have an SEO record for this model record

    $seoDetails = $this->seoModel->find(
        'first',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Seo.plugin' => $this->settings[$model->alias]['plugin'],
                'Seo.model' => $model->name,
                'Seo.foreign_key' => $modelPrimaryKey
            )
        )
    );

    if(empty($seoDetails)){
        $modelData = $model->read(null, $modelPrimaryKey);

        $slug = $model->getSlug($modelData[$model->alias]);
        $title = $model->getDisplayName($modelData[$model->alias]);

        $seoData = array(
            $this->seoModel->alias => array(
                'model' => $model->name,
                'plugin' => $this->settings[$model->alias]['plugin'],
                'foreign_key' => $model->id,
                'action' => 'view',
                'request_uri' => '/' . Inflector::underscore($model->name) . '/' . $slug,
                'title' => $title,
                'seo_attribute_type_id' => $this->defaultAttributeTypeId
            )
        );
        // Create some default meta tags as well
        $seoData['SeoMeta'] = array(
            0 => array(
                'key' => 'keywords',
                'value' => ''
            ),
            1 => array(
                'key' => 'description',
                'value' => ''
            )
        );

        $this->seoModel->create();
        $this->seoModel->saveAll($seoData);
        $id = $this->seoModel->id;

    }

}
```

And your SEO model might have this code inside it:

```
        /**
 * AfterSave function, called after an SEO item is saved
 * @param bool $created
 */
public function afterSave($created){

    parent::afterSave($created);

    // Now we need to create our cached routes file

    $this->createRouteFile();

    // Clear any cached routes
    CacheEngine::clearGroup('router');

}

/**
 * Cleans up a slug, preserving slash characters
 * @param $slug
 * @return string
 */
public function sanitizeSlug($slug){
    $slugParts = explode('/', $slug);

    foreach($slugParts as $slugIndex => $slugPart){
        $slugParts[$slugIndex] = $this->createSlugFromString($slugPart);
    }
    $slug = implode('/', $slugParts);

    return $slug;
}

/**
 * Creates/Updates the routes file by going through all the routes in the database and writing them to the routes file
 */
public function createRouteFile(){

    $databaseRoutes = $this->find(
        'all',
        array(
            'recursive' => -1,
            'fields' => array(
                'plugin',
                'model',
                'foreign_key',
                'action',
                'request_uri'
            )
        )
    );

    $fileContents = '';
    $fileContents .= "<?php\n";
    $fileContents .= "/** Automatically generated by " . __FILE__ . " on " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " */\n";


    foreach($databaseRoutes as $routeKey => $routeDetails){

        $routeLine = "Router::connect('" . addcslashes ( $routeDetails[$this->alias]['request_uri'], "'" ) . "', array(
            'plugin' => '" . addcslashes(Inflector::underscore($routeDetails[$this->alias]['plugin']), "'") . "',
            'controller' => '" . addcslashes(Inflector::underscore($routeDetails[$this->alias]['model']), "'") . "',
            'action' => '" . addcslashes($routeDetails[$this->alias]['action'], "'") . "',
            " . addcslashes($routeDetails[$this->alias]['foreign_key'], "'") . "));\n";

        $fileContents .= $routeLine;
    }

    // Write the routes data to our file.  Note that SEO_ROUTES_FILE is defined in /app/Module/Core/Config/Routes.php
    $success = file_put_contents(SEO_ROUTES_FILE, $fileContents);

    if(!$success){
        throw new Exception("SEO Routes file unwritable.  Check the permissions of: " . SEO_ROUTES_FILE);
    }
}
```

Good luck, it's a difficult problem, this solution is working quite well for me, and allows editing of any SEO url to whatever you want (even if it breaks the convention of your other pages).  This is useful when the client hires a specialist SEO company who wants to completely change the SEO urls of certain pages.